# Same changes in tag wiki excerpt and tag wiki but only one got approved

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, tag-wiki

I made an edit in the tag wiki for [exceldatareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exceldatareader) and removed the end date (changed *'97-2007* to *'97-*) since the official docs doesn't say anything else than it works for '97 and onwards (I tried it myself as well). However, [the edit to the tag wiki excerpt got approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14370494) but [the edit to the tag wiki didn't](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14370493). Right now it looks a bit strange. Why did one edit got approved but an identical got rejected? And why did my change even end up as two in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag excerpt and the tag wiki are two separate posts, so they are reviewed separately (even though it would make some sense to review them together). The tag excerpt has some additional rejection reasons (lacks usage guidance, circular tag definition) which don't make sense on a tag wiki. Note that it is also possible to change just one of them, but not the other.

Because they're two separate reviews, the reviews were done by different people (as can be seen from the links you provided). Different people have different standards for reviewing. IMHO, correcting wrong information like you did is a valid edit, especially when it comes to tags as those are viewed quite often. So you could try to edit the tag wiki again, and see if it gets accepted now. But note that if your edits are rejected [too often](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/295232), you will get temporarily suspended from editing.